# How to set the optimal padding used in newLatLngBounds method in google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Well I try to fit my markers and the direction from A to B I used

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
.include(route.startLocation)
.include(route.endLocation).build();
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 120));
```

in a real device (phone) of 4.5' it works fine, but should I change this padding automatically based on layout size? How can I do this? is it bad thinking?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can get pixel from dp

`public int getPixelFrom_dp(float dp) { return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension
(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,dp,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }`

and use it

```
int padding = getPixelFrom_dp(12);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding));
```